# Android SDK - Which ListItem has called the actual context menu?

Tags: android, listitem

First of all hello people, and sorry for my bad English, I'm Brazillian! I've been learning here in StackOverflow from the questions of other users ever since I started in Android; but now it is my turn to ask...

I made a soundboard app from a tutorial, but I decided to implement a new feature: Set as ringtone/notification. I am pretty sure that I'll have no problem to set an ogg file as a ringtone because I just saw an answer about it here... My question is how to get the ID of the listitem that called the context menu?

Take a look at my code (in portuguese toque/notificação means ringtone/notification):

```
registerForContextMenu(findViewById(android.R.id.list));
...
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menuc, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menuc, v, menuInfo);
        menuc.setHeaderTitle("Usar como");
        menuc.add(Menu.NONE, 0, Menu.NONE, "Toque");
        menuc.add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE,"Notificação");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getTitle() == "Toque") { toque(0,item.getItemId()); }  
        else if(item.getTitle() == "Notificação") { notificacao(0,item.getItemId()); }  
        else { return false; }
        return true;  
    }

    public void toque(int position,int id){  
        Sound s = (Sound) mSounds.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, s.getSoundResourceId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    }

    public void notificacao(int position,int id){  
        Sound s = (Sound) mSounds.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, s.getSoundResourceId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    }
```

So, as you can see I made a toast to test the parameters. Now I can get the res/raw/example.ogg by the number "0" but I want to dynamically get the ID of the ListView so I can pass it as the integer "position" ...

Example:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getTitle() == "Toque") { toque(GET.LISTITEM.ID, item.getItemId()); }
    else if (item.getTitle() == "Notificação"){ notificacao(GET.LISTITEM.ID, item.getItemId()); }
    else { return false; }
    return true;
}
```

I don't know if I was clear enough, or if it is possible, but I'm sure I'll be happy if I find a way to do it.

Thanks in advance, Lucas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a normal list box
`AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();`

`info.id` will get you the position.

So you can call 
`notificacao(info.id,item.getItemId())`

Comment: Thank you so much ! It works like a charm, but eclipse corrected me: calling (int) info.id,item.getItemId()

Comment: now I'm having trouble to set as ringtone LOL. Just what I though that would be easy since I have "res/raw/example.ogg" text. I've tried to adapt the code I found here with no sucess ... can you help me ?

Comment: I think it is impossible to set a private resource of your app as ringtone. You need a sound that resides on the filesystem.

Comment: Yeah, I imagine that ... so should have a way to save the resource in SD card, or not ?

Comment: I just got it ! https://market.android.com/details?id=br.com.blooti.chavinhogroove in a few hours the new version will be avaiable.

Answer (score 1):

Instead, if you want to implement twitter like Quick action badge (yes it was available in old twitter, check below image), i would suggest you implement [Quick Action bar](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/).

More about [Quick Action design pattern](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/03/ui-design-pattern-quick-actions.html).

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I'm starting so this is a bit more complicated =\

Comment: @user1127100 there is already a ready things available for download.